# pycrypto does not reproduce NIST test vectors for AES (CFB mode)

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto

This small python program should encrypt *plain* to *cipher* using AES in the CFB mode using a 128bit key

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

#            1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
key   = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
iv    = b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
plain = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
cipher = aes.encrypt(plain)

print(' '.join('{:2x}'.format(b) for b in cipher))
```

I took this key, IV and plain cipher combination from one of the [NIST test vectors](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/aes/KAT_AES.zip) (CFB128VarTxt128.rsp). For this particular combination I expect the cipher:

```
3a d7 8e 72 6c 1e c0 2b 7e bf e9 2b 23 d9 ec 34
```

but pycrypto calculates

```
3a 81 e1 d4 b8 24 75 61 46 31 63 4b 5c 79 d6 bc
```

The first byte is correct, whereas the others **do not match**. I also tried different test vectors, but the result stays the same. All bytes, except for the first byte, do not match.

I am quite sure, that the NIST test vectors are valid since I used them before when using AES with Crypto++ and I am also pretty sure, that the implementation of pycrypto is correct since its output agrees with online tools such as [this page](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/). Obviously, it is me, who is using the tools in an incorrect way...

Does anyone have a clue, how to reproduce the NIST test vectors with pycrypto?

This is the NIST example

```
# CAVS 11.1
# Config info for aes_values
# AESVS VarTxt test data for CFB128
# State : Encrypt and Decrypt
# Key Length : 128
# Generated on Fri Apr 22 15:11:53 2011
...
COUNT = 0
KEY = 00000000000000000000000000000000
IV = 80000000000000000000000000000000
PLAINTEXT = 00000000000000000000000000000000
CIPHERTEXT = 3ad78e726c1ec02b7ebfe92b23d9ec34
```

Comment: I'm getting the same results as you with PyCrypto 2.6.0...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a keyword argument, `segment_size`, in your [`AES.new(...)`](http://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html#new) call. This is the feedback size, and it defaults to 8. If your line of code is changed to

```
aes = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv, segment_size=128)
```

you get the correct result.

As stated in the docs:

> segment_size (integer) - (Only MODE_CFB).The number of bits the
>   plaintext and ciphertext are segmented in. It must be a multiple of 8.
>   If 0 or not specified, it will be assumed to be 8.

Your results correspond to what would likely be labeled "CFB8" in NIST docs.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Comment: thx for the RTFM. Now everything works as expected. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

I also get the same results as you when using AES.MODE_CFB, but I get the results you expect when I use AES.MODE_CBC instead.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def show(b):
    print(*['{:02x}'.format(u) for u in b])

key   = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
iv    = b'\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
plain = b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

crypto = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
cipher = crypto.encrypt(plain)
show(cipher)

# We need a fresh AES object to decrypt
crypto = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
decoded = crypto.decrypt(cipher)
show(decoded)
```

**output**

```
3a d7 8e 72 6c 1e c0 2b 7e bf e9 2b 23 d9 ec 34
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```